# Prebuilding a docker image *within* a Github Codespace when the image relies on the organization's other private repositories?

Tags: docker, github, codespaces, github-codespaces, devcontainer

I'm exploring how best to use Github Codespaces for my organization. Our dev environment consists of a Docker dev environment that we run on local machines. It relies on pulling other private repos we maintain via the local machine's ssh-agent. I'd ideally like to keep things as consistent as possible and have our Codespaces solution use the same Docker dev environment from *within* the codespace.

There's a naive solution of just building a new codespace with no `devcontainer.json` and going through all the setup for a dev environment each time you create a new one... but I'd like to avoid this. Ideally, I keep the same dev experience and am able to get the codespace to prebuild by building the docker image and somehow getting access to our other private repos.

An extremely hacky-feeling solution that works for automated building is creating an ssh key and storing it as a user codespace secret, then setting up the ssh-agent with that ssh-key as part of the `postCreateCommand`. My understanding is that this would *not* work with the `onCreateCommand` because ["it will not typically have access to user-scoped assets or secrets."](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#lifecycle-scripts). To reiterate, this works for automated building, but *not* pre-building.

From [this Github issue](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/12711) it looks like cloning via ssh is a complete no-go with prebuilds because ssh will need a user-defined ssh key, which isn't available from the `onCreateCommand`. The only potential workaround I can see for this is having an organization-wide read-only ssh-key... which seems potentially even sketchier than having user-created ssh keys as user secrets.

The other possibility I can think of is switching to https for the git clones. This would require [adding access to the other repos](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-repository-access-for-your-codespaces), which is no big deal. BUT I can't quite see how to get access from *within* the docker image. When I tried this, I was getting errors because I was asked for a username and password when I ran a `git clone` from within docker... even though `git clone` worked fine in the base codespace. Is there a way to forward whatever tokens Github uses for access to other repos into the docker build process? Is there a way to have user-generated tokens get passed into the docker build process and use that for access instead?

Thoughts and roasts welcome.